# Runtime Permission - Requesting permission for already granted permission

Tags: android, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I have written the below script to get multiple runtime permission for contacts and location. I am using two switches in the layout for contacts and locations respectively. If I click the Contact switch, its asking permission for both contacts and location as expected. Then I have manually removed the location permission from the "App Permissions" settings activity. Now If I click the location switch, again its asking for both contacts and location.

[image]

My question is, since I have granted the contacts permission in the first time and I can see the permission is granted in the "App Permissions" settings activity, why its again asking for the contacts permission? Even I am checking this in hasPermissions method.

```
public static final int REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 1001;
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS,
        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.basic_permissions);
    CONTACTS_ACCESS_SWITCH = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.contactsPermissionSwitch);
    LOCATION_ACCESS_SWITCH = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.locationPermissionSwitch);
    CONTACTS_ACCESS_SWITCH.setOnClickListener(requestPermissionMethod);
    LOCATION_ACCESS_SWITCH.setOnClickListener(requestPermissionMethod);
}

private void requestPermissionMethod() {
    if (!hasPermissions(BasicPermissions.this, PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(BasicPermissions.this, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }
}

private boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(BasicPermissions.this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Manifest File:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Config:**

Testing in Android 6.0 android studio emulator device.

compileSdkVersion 27.

minSdkVersion 18

targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code was written using Array, its requesting permission for all the values in the array even if it is already granted. So I have rewritten the code to use `ArrayList` instead of `Array`. Now its working perfectly as expected.

```
private  boolean requestPermissionMethod() {
    int permissionContacts = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    }
    if (permissionContacts != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS);
    }
    if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you request multiple permissions, it'll ask for multiple permissions.

If you only want it to request for the permissions that you don't currently have, you'll have to check for that yourself and then remove the permissions you already have from the "PERMISSIONS" array.

Comment: In the `hasPermissions()` method, I am already checking for the existing permissions and requesting permission only if the `hasPermissions()` method returns false. Is it not enough? Anything I am missing?

Comment: Thanks for your point. Please tell me whether I need to request for each permissions in the permission group? or is it fine to request single permission in each group. For example, If I request permission for READ_CONTACTS, Do I need to request another for WRITE_CONTACTS?

Comment: Even I am confused on the question asked by Vinoth. Anyone please advise?